# instanciar objetos

Tags: java

existe alguna forma de instanciar un objeto n cantidad de veces, es decir se que la instancia es

```
Objeto nombre_var = new Objeto();
```

es decir si quisiera instanciar una cantidad indeterminada de objetos dentro de un ciclo for

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
 Objeto x+'i' = new Objeto();
```

Algo como se hace con los indices de los vectores.
Muchas gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar una lista:

```
List<Objeto> objetos = new ArrayList<>();
for(i = 0; i<5; i++){
    objetos.add(new Objeto());
}
```

Con lo que acceder al cuarto objeto sería

```
objetos.get(3);
```

Si sabes la cantidad exacta de instancias, podrías directamente usar un array:

```
Objeto [] objetos= new Objeto[5];
    for(int i = 0; i<5; i++){
    objetos[0] = new Objeto();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que deseas crear es un array estático deberías poner algo así:

```
Objeto []nombre_var = new Objeto[Capacidad_Deseada];    
for(int i =0; i< 200; i++)
    {
        Objeto aux = new Objeto();
        hola[i] = aux;

    }
```

Si lo que quieres es utilizar memoria dinámica, puedes utilizar arraylist o listas enlazadas.